# Determine Windows version via application

Tags: c++, c, windows

I wanted to ask, is there any possibility to determine the Windows version via the application, I have made some research, but haven't found, 
Thank you in advance ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Err... How about [GetVersionEx()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724451%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) ?